# Laravel redirect from private method with errors

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, if-statement, laravel-5

I have the following code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $this->validateData($request->all());

        // store something

        return redirect()->action('controller@index')->withMessage( 'Saved Successfully' );
}

private function validateData($requestParams)
{
    try 
    {
        $validator->validate( $requestParams );
    } 
    catch ( ValidationException $e ) 
    {
        redirect()->action('controller@create')->withInput()->withErrors( $e->get_errors() )->send();
        exit(); // this causes the withErrors to not be there
    }
}
```

If I remove the `exit();`, the error messages will appear, but also the store function will be executed (see `// store something`). I know I can rewrite my code like:

```
if($this->validateData($request->all()))
{
    // store something

    return redirect()->action('controller@index')->withMessage( 'Saved Successfully' );
}
```

But I don't want the ugly `if` statement here. There must be a way to redirect with the flash messages without it.

Comment: The solution belongs in the answer by [Hieu Le](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1399505/hieu-le), and not in the question. Please try to remember, this is a **Q**uestion and **A**nswer site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Update your private method code like this to make the redirection work with `$errors` variable visible:

```
private function validateData($requestParams)
{
    try 
    {
        $validator->validate( $requestParams );
    } 
    catch ( ValidationException $e ) 
    {
        $resp = redirect()->action('WelcomeController@index')->withInput()->withErrors($e->get_errors());
        \Session::driver()->save();
        $resp->send();
        exit();
    }
}
```

#### explaination

When exiting in the middle of your controller, there are some job which is executed in the application termination will not be execute anymore. In your case, the Session middleware `terminate` method will not be called. Let see its content ([ref](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L85)):

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    if ($this->sessionHandled && $this->sessionConfigured() && ! $this->usingCookieSessions())
    {
        $this->manager->driver()->save();
    }
}
```

Now, look at the `save` method of our Session driver ([ref](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L249))

```
public function save()
{
    $this->addBagDataToSession();
    $this->ageFlashData();
    $this->handler->write($this->getId(), $this->prepareForStorage(serialize($this->attributes)));
    $this->started = false;
}
```

As you can see, your flash data is only be saved when the Session middleware terminates successfully. With your old code, the flash data will be lost!

What I do with my code is calling the `save` method manually before sending our response to the browser. However, I still recommend you bring the redirection to the public controller method.

Comment: Ok, I will try this in a bit. On my lunchbreak now. Seems logically

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see any problem using the if statement there. Basically you do not stop the code execution, so thats why the store function is executed, even if your validation fails. The redirect function just sends a header with the redirect location, it does not abort the code after it to be executed. It works with `exit()`, because it sends the redirect headers and stop the rest of the code to be exeuted.

This is not ugly, it is clean and clear and I suggest you to use this. This is a good example of right `if` statement usage - if one conditions i met then do this. In your case if your validation passes, just store the object. (Just remember to modify your validate function to return true or false)

```
if($this->validateData($request->all()))
{
    // store something

    return redirect()->action('controller@index')->withMessage( 'Saved Successfully' );
}
```

The other possible solution is to use `try .. catch` block like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $this->validateData($request->all());

        // store something

        return redirect()->action('controller@index')->withMessage( 'Saved Successfully' );
    } catch ( ValidationException $e ) {
        return redirect()->action('controller@create')->withInput()->withErrors( $e->get_errors() );
    }
}

private function validateData($requestParams)
{
    // Your validation logic here
    $validator->validate( $requestParams );
}
```

Comment: It's getting ugly if you call a private function in the private function again. You will need to do the if statement in every function and you get a if statement chain..

Answer (score -1):

you just forgot to 'return' after the validation exception :D, then you would not have to 'exit;'

Comment: Then it still executes the `// store something`

Comment: I assume maybe that is because you are redirecting to the wrong action (the one that requires POST request). Maybe 'controller@create' - is the method responsible for processing the POST data?

Comment: No everything is okay. And the return will only return and execute the `// store something`.

Comment: Oh, I got it - I hav completely misunderstood you, well deserved minus :D. Actually I don't know how to avoid using 'If' statement. You can check all popular Laravel codebases - they stick to using the 'if' statement to check the validation. Here is an example https://github.com/LaravelIO/laravel.io/blob/master/app/controllers/ArticlesController.php